# Reference number

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

In an attempt to write an article in the template provided by the journal "Letters in Mathematical Physics" I have encountered a problem with the reference number in the text. My reference list has 16 items but when cited, the reference number shows only from 1 to 9 only, that is, when references appearing in the first and tenth onwards each is showing as [1] instead of [10],[11] etc.

I have tried to list the references separately using a **.bib** file, **.bbl** file and even a **.tex** file and used the `\input` command but none of the three processes solved the issue.

The template can be found at:
https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support

I must add that the class file uses **natbib** package.

Please help me resolve the issue. Any clue is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please (1) post a link to the template so we don't have to try to track it down ourselves, and (2) post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that generates the problem. It would require a crystal ball to know what's causing the problem without being able to replicate it ourselves.

Comment: The template has a sample file `sn-article.tex`, which itself has 12 references, and [10], [11] and [12] work fine for me. Do you get the problem with that sample file as well? If not, there must be something in your code that's different and relevant. Without seeing your code, there's no way for us to know what it is. I'm repeating myself now, but a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) is needed here.